# Identify and Delete Orphan Snapshots in AWS that are 12 months old

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, snapshot

I have a thousand number of snapshots in my AWS Account that are 12 months old. So have to delete the snapshots that are 12 months old. But the challenge here is, I have to identify the Orphan Snapshots(Not attached/created to/by any AMI) and delete them first.

Please help me add a script to identify the orphan snapshots that are more than 12 months old.

Please help me with a script.

```html
#!/bin/bash

set -e

AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=<ENTER_YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID_HERE>
REGION=us-west-2
ORPHANED_SNAPSHOTS_COUNT_LIMIT=10

WORK_DIR=/tmp

aws ec2 --region $REGION describe-snapshots --owner-ids $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID --query Snapshots[*].SnapshotId --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | sort > $WORK_DIR/all_snapshots
aws ec2 --region $REGION describe-images --filters Name=state,Values=available --owners $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID --query "Images[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].Ebs.SnapshotId" --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | sort > $WORK_DIR/snapshots_attached_to_ami

ORPHANED_SNAPSHOT_IDS=`comm -23 <(sort $WORK_DIR/all_snapshots) <(sort $WORK_DIR/snapshots_attached_to_ami)`

if [ -z "$ORPHANED_SNAPSHOT_IDS" ]; then
  echo "OK - no orphaned (not attached to any AMI) snapshots found"
  exit 0
fi

ORPHANED_SNAPSHOT_IDS=`echo "$ORPHANED_SNAPSHOT_IDS" | grep "snap"`

ORPHANED_SNAPSHOTS_COUNT=`echo "$ORPHANED_SNAPSHOT_IDS" | wc -l`

if (( ORPHANED_SNAPSHOTS_COUNT > ORPHANED_SNAPSHOTS_COUNT_LIMIT )); then
  echo "CRITICAL - $ORPHANED_SNAPSHOTS_COUNT orphaned (not attached to any AMI) snapshots found: [ $ORPHANED_SNAPSHOT_IDS ]"
  echo "To delete them, use commands below:"
  IFS=$'\n'
  for snapshot_id in $ORPHANED_SNAPSHOT_IDS; do echo "aws ec2 --region us-west-2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $snapshot_id"; done
  exit 1
else
  echo "OK - $ORPHANED_SNAPSHOTS_COUNT orphaned (not attached to any AMI) snapshots found"
  if (( ORPHANED_SNAPSHOTS_COUNT > 0 )); then
    echo "[ $ORPHANED_SNAPSHOT_IDS ]"
  fi
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: I think this would be easier to write, and more robust, if it were written in Python (using boto3).

Comment: Sorry, no free coding services on S.O. Include your best attempt to solve the problem and other will help. Mostly good code, but if you're using `(( math eval ))`, then join the 90's and use `var=$(cmd substition)` instead of back-quotes ;-). It's unclear how you want the date check to be integrated into your code, AND adding that to this, will make this (IMHO) an unmanageable Q. Why not pare it down to just the code that you need to create. Include what command generates the date values and some sample output from that command (2-3 lines, but cover any corner cases you can identify).GoodLuck!

Comment: @jarmod thanks for your suggestion. Have coded in python boto 3 as well .But finding difficulties in the same. If You have used one earlier, please help. Thanks

Comment: Note there are numerous github projects with similar goals, for example: https://github.com/miztiik/serverless-janitor-ebs-snapshots

Comment: jarmod, Thanks for that., But that should have Tags, wherein my snapshots doesn't have them.

Comment: You may wish to verify this, but EBS should throw an error if you try to delete a snapshot associated with an AMI... so you can theoretically just delete any snapshot over 12 months old and any that can't be deleted can be assumed to be associated with an AMI, not orphaned.